can any one explain in detail about Vite renderBuiltUrl?
I am using react web app using vite as build tool
after building my application all the assets ( js, css, svg, png, jpg ) generated in build folder
in vite config i defined base: https://x.y.com
in this case all the assets will be dowloaded from the above base url
Ex: 
   https://x.y.com/assets/index.asdasd.js
   https://x.y.com/assets/print.qwjhgkjf.svg

it works totally fine.
But what I have now is all my assets are in 2 different cdns

all image assets are in https://img.x.com/...
all other assets are in https://js.x.com/....

I have to configure vite as below
    experimental: {
      renderBuiltUrl(filename: string, { hostId, hostType, type }) {
    
        const paths = filename.split('.');
        const ext = paths[paths.length - 1];
        
        if (hostType !== 'html') {
          if (imgExt[ext]) {
            return { runtime: 'https://img.x.com' };
          }
          return { runtime: 'https://js.x.com' };
        } else {
          return { relative: true };
        }
  }

but it is throwing me error that
[vite:css-post] { runtime: "https://img.x.com/ }" is not supported for assets in css files: assets/leftArrow.e0fcee6e.svg
error during build:
Error: { runtime: "https://img.x.com/ }" is not supported for assets in css files: assets/leftArrow.e0fcee6e.svg


It's possible to use "runtime" options only for js files (not assets like css, images etc).
So the config should be something like this:
experimental: {
  renderBuiltUrl(filename: string, { hostType }) {
    const ext = filename.split('.').at(-1);

    if (hostType === 'js') {
      return { runtime: 'https://js.x.com' }
    }
        
    if (imgExt[ext]) {
      return 'https://img.x.com';
    }

    return { relative: true };
}

